# Как ввести строку и число в 1 строку

Tags: python

надо, что бы при вводе Macbook 1500, Macbook становилось str, а 1500 int

пользователь вводит : Macbook 1500
и они делятся на int и str

Comment: Вы уже что-то успели попробовать сделать?

Comment: а в чем проблема-то?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться следующей функцией:

```
def split_input(input_string):
    input_list = input_string.split()
    string_part = input_list[0]
    int_part = int(input_list[1])
    return (string_part, int_part)
```

Пример использования:

```
result = split_input("Macbook 1500")
print(result) # ('Macbook', 1500)
```

Comment: Название функции так себе.

Comment: Название функции выбирал по смыслу действия функции :) А что именно не так?

Comment: Как по названию "разделить ввод" надо понять, что функция делит строку на название и число? Лучше было бы parse что-то и без input. Я вначале думал про parse_model, но что-то по примеру число больше на цену похоже, так что что-то в духе parse_title_with_price. Ну и тут уже вызывает вопросы, могут ли быть внутри заголовка пробелы - если да, то твоя реализация сломается.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо.